# Multiple try/except , next one catch exception after first one handle it

Tags: python, django, exception, django-rest-framework

I have two try except blocks, the second one triggers the first one's exception.

I'm expecting that the first one handle the first exception and that the second one not trigger that exception.

The second try/catch block catch the exception generated in the first one unless I handle it, why?  Can someone help me solve this issue?

```py
try:
    if isinstance(request.data['name'],str):
        progetto.name = request.data['name']   
        progetto.save()
    else:
        raise TypeError('Validation error')
except TypeError as te:
    print('type error catched error: ',te)
    errori.append({'name': str(te)})
except Exception as e:
    print('name catched error: ',e)
    errori.append({'name': str(e)})

try:
    progetto.expiration = request.data['expiration']
    progetto.save()
except Exception as ex:
    print('exp block catched error: ',ex)
    errori.append({'expiration': str(ex)})
```

Comment: Correct indentation might help to understand what's happening

Comment: No, what will happen is that you set the attribute, so if the name is invalid, your `.save()` will again error on the `name`. But using the save mechanism for validation is a bad idea.

Comment: it's right i want to raise an exception if is not a string and antoher if the name is not unique, in my models i set unique = True in the name field. But the exception for unique name is being catched even in the second try/except block

Comment: @user21000937: of course, since you set the name, try to save it, the database rejects, you catch the exception, you set the expiration, and you try to save it again, with the name still on it, hence the database rejects it a second time. This is one of the (very) long list of reasons why manual validation, and especially using the database as the "working horse" is a bad idea.

Comment: i've understand my error, now i can see where the error is unless i have handle the exception the wrong  name is still prepared for saving, so when i do the save in the other field i get the same error. I think it should be a better way to validate data in django, i'm new at programing and new whit this tecnology. Thank you soo much for the help

Answer (score 0):

> The second `try`/`catch` block catch the exception generated in the first one unless i handle it, why? can someone help me solve this issue ?

Not really no. What *will* happen however is that you set the name of `.name` of the `progetto`, and if that is invalid, and you save it, not much will happen, except that you add an error to the log.

Then you add the `.expiration`, but the `.name` is still there, so if there is an integrity error on the name part, the invalid name will still be there, and thus raise this a second time.

But using the saving mechanism to spot invalid data is a *very* bad idea. For example in this case it is possible that if the `.expiration` is not set, the database will reject it anyway, so you can not really tell what caused the problem.

Another thing is that a lot of validation can not be done (effectively) at the database side, for example an [**`EmailField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#emailfield) is a `CharField` with validators at the Django side, the database thus does not check if the entered data is indeed an email address, but Django can.

What you are here trying to do manually already exists, this is the task of a [**(`Model`)`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/), or a [**`Serializer`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) in case of the Django REST framework. These take into account all sorts of validators both at the Django side, and the database side (like `CheckConstraint`s and `UniqueConstraint`s to validate that the item indeed exists).

A form is exactly designed to run validation on all fields, and generate a collection of errors: with `my_form.errors` you get a dictionary that maps the name of the field on a list of possible errors.

Manually processing request data is cumbersome: there is no guarantee that the request contains all required data items, and that these all are in the correct format. Exactly because it is cumbersome, and a severe security risk, doing it manually is almost never a good idea.